# Can't get XML element with colon in the name using TouchXML

Tags: iphone, xml, touchxml

I have the following code:

```
NSString *subtitle = [[[node elementsForName:@"subtitle"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
NSString *duration = [[[node elementsForName:@"itunes:duration"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
```

The first line works perfectly. The second line though won't work. I assume it has something to do with namespaces, but I'm pretty new to all of this so I would appreciate any guidance. Thank you!

---

It turns out that I can use the `elementsForLocalName:URI:` to read the element correctly. Now the problem is that since I am using the TouchXML library, it doesn't seem like that method has been mapped over to the `CXMLElement` structure (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241857/parsing-an-nsxmlelement-in-cocoa)).

So the question now is: how can I convert a `CXMLElement` to an `NSXMLElement` so that I can use that method?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of node in the debugger? When you say won't work, does that mean duration is nil or you get an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"itunes" is the namespace identifier. It doesn't actually have any significance on its own, it just links a URI with the element in question. It looks like you're using the iTunes RSS extensions, which live under the namespace `http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd`.

So, for namespaced elements, I think (I'm not familiar with Objective-C or NSXML :P) you want to use [`elementsForLocalName`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead:

```
[node elementsForLocalName: @"duration" URI: @"http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"]
```

---

For the answer to the second question, see comments below.

Comment: Thanks Porges, I think that is exactly right. But now there's another issue -- see my edit above.

Comment: It looks like, if you can get the actual prefix used by the XML document (so whatever `xmlns:____="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"` is), you should be able to just use `elementsForName: @"____:duration"`.

Comment: That's not working either -- the _____ is "itunes". Looks like I may need to either switch to another library or somehow make a re-formatted proxy for the XML feed from iTunes. I appreciate your help Porges!

Comment: Actually, after looking at the TouchXML source, it looks like just `elementsForName: @"duration"` might work... ignoring namespaces completely.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that worked. Thank you for looking into the source code, this is a big help!